# Flexbox / force a 2 column layout at all times (input is only 1 array of objects)

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have an array of objects that I get from the server us an Ajax call and I need to display the one array as a two column layout at all times. the columns should be balanced. Using flex-direction: column just expands the page indefinitely. I want to make sure that there are two columns all the time.

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 90vh;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h1> Group 1 </h1>
    <div class="details">
      <h4> Object 1</h4>
      <h4> Object 2</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h1> Group 2 </h1>
  <div class="details">
    <h4> Object 1</h4>
    <h4> Object 2</h4>
    <h4> Object 3</h4>
    <h4> Object 4</h4>
    <h4> Object 5</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h1> Group 3</h1>
  <div class="details">
    <h4> Object 1</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h1> Group 4 </h1>
  <div class="details">
    <h4> Object 1</h4>
    <h4> Object 2</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h1> Group 5 </h1>
  <div class="details">
    <h4> Object 1</h4>
    <h4> Object 2</h4>
    <h4> Object 3</h4>
    <h4> Object 4</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) seems appropriate here,also mind, as already stated,  the html structure of `.container` including only one `.item`, you closed it too early i believe.

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
}

.container {
  column-count: 2;
}

.item {
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0 0.5em 1em;
  background: lightblue;
  break-inside: avoid;
  /* remove this to allow item to break to next column , demo below the first container */
}
h1 {margin:0  ;}
.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #bee/* demo see us */
}

.container~.container .item {
  break-inside: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h1> Group 1 </h1>
    <div class="details">
      <h4> Object 1</h4>
      <h4> Object 2</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h1> Group 2 </h1>
    <div class="details">
      <h4> Object 1</h4>
      <h4> Object 2</h4>
      <h4> Object 3</h4>
      <h4> Object 4</h4>
      <h4> Object 5</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1> Group 3</h1>
    <div class="details">
      <h4> Object 1</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1> Group 4 </h1>
    <div class="details">
      <h4> Object 1</h4>
      <h4> Object 2</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1> Group 5 </h1>
    <div class="details">
      <h4> Object 1</h4>
      <h4> Object 2</h4>
      <h4> Object 3</h4>
      <h4> Object 4</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h1> Group 1 </h1>
    <div class="details">
      <h4> Object 1</h4>
      <h4> Object 2</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h1> Group 2 </h1>
    <div class="details">
      <h4> Object 1</h4>
      <h4> Object 2</h4>
      <h4> Object 3</h4>
      <h4> Object 4</h4>
      <h4> Object 5</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1> Group 3</h1>
    <div class="details">
      <h4> Object 1</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1> Group 4 </h1>
    <div class="details">
      <h4> Object 1</h4>
      <h4> Object 2</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1> Group 5 </h1>
    <div class="details">
      <h4> Object 1</h4>
      <h4> Object 2</h4>
      <h4> Object 3</h4>
      <h4> Object 4</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You close your `.container` too early.
I'll add to your code `flex-direction:row`

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;/* new */
  flex-wrap:wrap;/* new */
  height: 90vh;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 1 50%;/*new*/
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h1> Group 1 </h1>
    <div class="details">
      <h4> Object 1</h4>
      <h4> Object 2</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h1> Group 2 </h1>
    <div class="details">
      <h4> Object 1</h4>
      <h4> Object 2</h4>
      <h4> Object 3</h4>
      <h4> Object 4</h4>
      <h4> Object 5</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <h1> Group 3</h1>
    <div class="details">
      <h4> Object 1</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <h1> Group 4 </h1>
    <div class="details">
      <h4> Object 1</h4>
      <h4> Object 2</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <h1> Group 5 </h1>
    <div class="details">
      <h4> Object 1</h4>
      <h4> Object 2</h4>
      <h4> Object 3</h4>
      <h4> Object 4</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thank you Sfili_81, one followup - is there anyway the space between Group 3 and Group 5 be collapsed?

Comment: Do you want some space on margin-bottom?

Comment: No, basically:  Group 1 has 2 objects, Group 2 has 5 objects; Group 3 which has one object starts only at the end of the first row; I wanted Group 3 object to start right after Group 1 object.